# tcp client which makes many outgoing connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp

My TCP client need to connect to thousands servers (in local network) all at once.
Communication is simple. 10 bytes string TCP request, 20 bytes response.

I have gigabit network.

when client connects servers one by one no issues.
But when all at once I have success with 1000 servers and others failing with errors: normally no route to host.

My clients running on brandnew  NUC with i7.
I was tweaking TCP stack :

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
mtu 500, 3000, 9000
ulimit -n 32000 2000 3000 5000
```

But no success.
Best I managed to get is 1800 connections
Do u know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix that issue so let me share how:
with dmesg i find out that:

```
> [145307.501197] neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
> [145307.567830] neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
> [145308.354244] neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
> [145308.479650] neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
```

so solution was to increase ARP table:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1=16000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2=20000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3=24000
```